# Generate URL (url_for) with Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to generate urls for mails with an application in API mode?

I want to generate a URL of type: "host/confirmation/token"?

I tested:

```
<%= url_for("confirm/#{@token}") %>
```

Result:

```
confirm/JtuQW54DkZXtAnhm
```

But host are not present, how to put "host" inside ?

I configured:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
     host: "lol.com"
  }
```

Comment: [url_for](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for) definition says that `only_path` is `true` by default, did you tried `only_path: false` as params of `url_for` call?

Answer (score 3):

You just have to set `:only_path` to `false` on your url_for call, like:

```
<%= url_for({ action: "confirm", token_id: @token, controller: "controller_name", only_path: false }) %>
```

Comment: `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
      host: "lol.com",
      only_path: false
  }` I tested this but same problem

Comment: not on your `default_url_options`, but on your `url_for` call

Comment: `ActionView::Template::Error: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)`, Impossible

Comment: just edited my answer with the right syntax, but basically, you have to define action, controller and params (if the url contain a variable, like create routes that accepts ids, you can pass this as `id:`. You can also always read more on [rails api dock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for)

Answer (score 1):

You did not put your routes file, I don't know how to work routes file.

You can follow something like this

```
url_for controller: 'tasks', action: 'testing', host: 'lol.com'
# => 'http://lol.com/tasks/testing'
```

For more explanation go to [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for)

Comment: `ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches`, its API mode, the url is different between the server and the client, i would like generate URL depending on "production" or "developpemnt" env

Comment: That's why need to check your routes file

Comment: routes files containes routes for API, no routes for client, the link in email redirect to CLIENT, no API.
`url_for` mapping for routes, the routes on client are different, do u understand ?

Comment: I&#39;m sorry I didn't understood this before, but in this case I will use something different than url_for to do that. Try to save your URL domain in some variable or method defined on application controller and get it when build the route